# Batch file to identify 0 from a txt file which contain file name(e.g.ABCDE01)and trigger message display that 0 found together with the file name/path

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file to find 0 from a text file. What I required is to find only 0 integer from the left column instead of detecting 0 integer from the file name, e.g. `ABCDE01-1`, `FGHIJ01-1` and etc. on the right column of the text file. When 0 is detected, a message must display that 0 has been found together with the file name/folder path which contains 0 in the left column (e.g file name: `FGHIJ01` / folder path: `D:\FOLDER A\ FGHIJ01.MOV`).

Please refer to my batch file below and advice how to edit this to fulfill this requirement. My Text File:

```
5916 D:\FOLDER A\ ABCDE01.MOV/ 0 D:\FOLDER A\ FGHIJ01.MOV
```

My Batch file script:

```
@echo off find "0" <"C:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome.txt" >nul && echo ERROR:FOUND ZERO SIZE IN THE FILE!!! & pause
```

Comment: Are the numeric values always of the form N.NNNN? Does the file contain anything else? If so, are the numeric values in predictable locations?

Comment: No, it's not always N.NNNN. This file also contains name of the file e.g. ABC01, ABC02 ..etc and file size in KB.. When i use my script, it finds 0 not from file size but also from name of the file. Any idea where i can edit this script to work on this requirement?

Comment: You'll need to use something better than `find`. A combination of `grep` and some further processing, or perhaps a Perl script—even a relatively simple one-liner would do it, for example: `perl -ne 'print "Zero found in $ARGV\n" if /((\d|\.)+)/g and $1 == 0' *.txt`—This finds `0`, `0.0`, `0.00` etc., but would not match on `ABC01`, `1468`, or `0.00001`.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i will post a new question since my explanation is not very clear i guess. I will include my batch script too.

Comment: You should modify this question instead of posting a new question if you want to change how you're asking the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Any idea how i can edit this script? I am just learning about batch file script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command does what you want, assuming that the 0 appears on its own on a line, with no other characters (as shown in your latest edit):

```
findstr /B /E "0" test.txt > nul && echo Found zero
```

The `/B /E "0"` finds a 0 that's both at the beginning and end of a line.

If you want to look clever, you can do the same with this:

```
findstr /R "^0$" test.txt > nul && echo Found 0
```

...and to process a bunch of files and display only the names of files that contain such a 0:

```
findstr /M /R "^0$" *.txt
```

If the 0 isn't alone on a line (but is at the start), you'll need to use a slightly different search patten:

```
findstr /R "^0\>" test.txt > nul && echo Found zero
```

This matches a 0 at the start of the line (that's what `^` is for), but has a space or some other non-word character immediately after it.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i tried just now but it cannot detect the zero. It display the CMD and stated press any key to continue... Well, this is the script that i use: @echo off
findstr /R "^0$" test.txt > nul && echo Found 0 & pause

Comment: Did you use your own file name? I used "test.txt" on my own local machine. Also, make sure the "0" is on a line on its own, because that's what the expression expects. If the 0 has spaces before or after it, you'll need to include those characters in the search  expression

Comment: yes i used my own file .txt. If you see my "MY Text File" above, 5916(File size)  D:\FOLDER A\ ABCDE01.MOV(Folder path) in 1st row. 0(File size) D:\FOLDER A\ FGHIJ01.MOV(Folder path) in 2nd row.

Comment: Oh, in that case it won't work; my first answer assumed the 0 was alone on a line. I've added another syntax at the end that you can try.

Comment: yes it is working now but is it possible if it can display the folder name or path with 0 file size found? E.g: if  0(File size) D:\FOLDER A\ FGHIJ01.MOV(Folder path) in 2nd row and this will display "Found Zero". Will it b able to display the file name or path together, e.g "Found Zero FGHIJ(File name)"

Comment: Yes. Remove the `> nul` and everything after it, like this: `findstr /R "^0\>" test.txt`. You can perform more interesting text processing and translation with other tools like Perl, as I mentioned in my comment under your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, it is working now. I cannot use Perl script because i cannot download this application and no internet connection for that machine. It has only notepad so i guess, batch file is the better option. Anyway, Perl script looks good. I will try to learn it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Welcome to stackoverflow, and don't forget to mark the correct answers as accepted, and to upvote answers (not only on your own questions) that you find useful and interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming format is always 0.0000, this should do it:

```
@echo off
find "0.0000" <"C:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome.txt" >nul && echo ERROR:FOUND ZERO SIZE IN THE FILE!!! & pause
```

Comment: Just commenting here that `10.0000` will match too.  The OP can use `" 0.0000"` if there is a leading space or perhaps `findstr /r "^0\.0000"` if it is at the start of a line.

Answer (score 0):

try this with a bit of `Regex`:

```
findstr "\<0.0000\>" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\outcome.txt" >nul && (
    echo ERROR:FOUND ZERO SIZE IN THE FILE!!! 
    pause
)
```

`\<` is the Regex for `start of a word`
`\>` is the Regex for `end of a word`
A Regex word contains `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.